# Lock the view in Tabs Outliner

Tags: chromium, browser-tabs, tabs, outline

#### Scenario:

In [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl), let's say [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home) has three windows open:

- Window A, 10 tabs.
- Window B, 30 tabs.
- Window C, Tabs Outliner.

All of three windows and 40 tabs fit in [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) with no scroll.

#### Now the problem is:

Whenever I change window, [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) auto scrolls in order to have that window on top. So if window A is focused, I can see everything; but if window B is, I can only see its 30 tabs.

#### Simple question:

**How to lock [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) into not doing this?**

---

Have a couple pictures exemplifying what I describe.

I like this (you can free hand draw a smiling smiley if you fancy):

[image: a screenshot of my laptop]

I don't like this (you can free hand draw a sad smiley if you fancy):

[image: another screenshot of my laptop]

> *They say a picture is worth
>
>     a thousand words,
>
>   well I know Ffmpeg and I say
>
>     a video can actually be
>
>     a thousand pictures.*
>
> --- john.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that if I change tab and/or window through clicking it in [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) (instead of cycling windows through the use of `cmd`+`<` or `cmd`+`>`), the issue/feature/bug above doesn't reproduce.

That's better than nothing, but it is highly unsatisfactory, as requires moving the fingers down to the track pad from the keyboard.